# Removing the spacing between tiles in tilesheet

Tags: photoshop, tile

So I have an image which contains a tile-sheet, where each tile is approx 16 pixels wide, and high. But there spaced out with a transparent spacer between each tile.
Like so:

[image: Have]

But this is ugly, and makes displaying the sprites in the program annoying, not to mention it wastes valuable image space. Is there any easy (Besides me manually using Photoshop to move each individual tile) way to make it look like this?

[image: Want]

I looked through Photoshop macros, as-well as other programs and I diden't seem to find anything that would directly do this.
Google also suggests I go to home-depo and get tile caulk remover.

Comment: You could possible automate this with a script, but I'd need to know more about your source document.  Is each tile in its own layer?  Is the gap always the same number of pixels? Are the tiles always the same number of pixels? Any chance of actually linking to the source document?

Comment: All on same layer, exactly one pixel separating every tile. the first one is in the correct place. And the tiles are always 16 x 16.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this snippet.  As you said, it assumes tiles are always going to be 16 pixels. Top left one is in the correct position and a single pixel gap.  The script assumes the document will opened with the layer containing your tiles set as the active layer.

```
#target photoshop
app.preferences.rulerUnits = Units.PIXELS;
app.preferences.typeUnits = TypeUnits.PIXELS;

var gap = 1;
var tileSize = 16;
var doc = app.activeDocument.duplicate();
var sourceLyr = doc.activeLayer;
var xTilePosition = 0;
var yTilePosition = 0;

for (var x = 0; x < sourceLyr.bounds[2]; x = x+ tileSize + 1 ) {

    for (var y = 0; y < sourceLyr.bounds[3]; y = y + tileSize + 1) {

        if (x > 0 || y > 0) {
            app.activeDocument = doc;
            doc.activeLayer = sourceLyr;
            selRegion = Array(Array(x, y),
                                    Array(x + tileSize, y),
                                    Array(x + tileSize, y + tileSize),
                                    Array(x, y + tileSize),
                                    Array(x, y))
            doc.selection.select(selRegion);

            var dx = x - (xTilePosition * tileSize);
            var dy = y - (yTilePosition * tileSize);

            doc.selection.translate(0 - dx, 0 - dy);
        }

        yTilePosition ++;
    }

    xTilePosition++;
    yTilePosition = 0;
}
```

Comment: Running now, may take a few. tileset is.... 9600 x 9600.
Added a try catch on the translate just in case the tile is empty.

Comment: Seems to have worked perfectly, Going to now google the part of it so i can read up on the api. Thanks!

Comment: this doesn't work if there are transparent pixels in the layer